# Why does not my code give the last two numbers?

Tags: c++, numbers

I have written a C++ program to find all the automorphic numbers (numbers which are repeated in the final digits of their squares such as **5x5**=2**5**, **76x76**=57**76**) from 1 to 111,111. The program runs fine except that it fails to give 90625 and 109376. The code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  long int square;
  int a, sum = 0, result, b;

  for (int i = 1; i < 111111; i++) {
    result = 1;
    b = i;

    while (b > 0){
      b = b / 10;
      result = result * 10;
    }

    square = i * i;

    a = square % result;

    if(i == a){
      sum = sum + i;
      cout << i << endl;
    }
  }

  cout << sum << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... And format the code to make it readable

Comment: You could, for example, modify the code to only test 90625 and to log before and after each computation.

Comment: Also, what's the point of storing the result of multiplying two `int`s in a `long int`?

Comment: Because the square of 111,111 could possibly require more bytes to be stored than an 'int' @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @hamasahmed yes but then you should convert i to `long int` like this `square = (long int)i * (long int)i`

Comment: @hamasahmed 1) A `long int` is not guaranteed to be wider than an `int`. 2) THe multiplication is done according to the operand's types. It does not care how you use the result.

Comment: @hamasahmed If the square of 111,111 could require more bytes than can be stored in an `int`, then `i*i` will overflow. Storing the overflow result in a `long int` won't help, since it's an `int`. (What you do with a result has no effect on how it's computed. If the multiplication overflows, the result will be wrong. Storing it in a larger type won't help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long int has only 4 bytes

```
long    4 bytes -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned long   4 bytes 0 to 4,294,967,295
```

The square of **90625 and 109376 are 8,212,890,625 and 11,963,109,376** respectively. So as the values overflow, you won't be able to produce those two values in long int limit. You can use integer type `long long`.

```
long long   8 bytes –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
unsigned long long   8 bytes 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

And if you want to use bigger numbers you can handle them using `Arrays` or let libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org) to handle larger numbers.